# OrientDB: Internal server error:com.orientechnologies.orient.core.command.OCommandExecutorNotFoundException

Tags: orientdb

While executing a query in OrientDB's Graph editor window, I am getting the below

Internal server error:
com.orientechnologies.orient.core.command.OCommandExecutorNotFoundException: Cannot find a command executor for the command request: sql.{"command":"select from V","mode":"graph"} [ONetworkProtocolHttpDb]
[enter image description here][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/diuXb.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had set the class path for orientdb, it resolve issue.
OREINTDB_HOME={orientdb directory}